# Ruby Grouping nested array

Tags: ruby

how from this:

```
[
    ["1", "className", "Connection"], 
    ["2", "className", "Connection"], 
    ["1", "connectorId", "100"], 
    ["2", "connectorId", "100"], 
    ["1", "part_1", "side_1"], 
    ["2", "part_1", "side_1"], 
    ["1", "part_2", "bottomPanel_1"], 
    ["2", "part_2", "bottomPanel_1"], 
    ["1", "transformation", nil], 
    ["2", "transformation", nil]
]
```

resive something like this:

```
[    
    [["1", "className", "Connection"], 
    ["1", "connectorId", "100"], 
    ["1", "part_2", "bottomPanel_1"], 
    ["1", "part_1", "side_1"],
    ["1", "transformation", nil]], 
    
    [["2", "part_1", "side_1"],
    ["2", "className", "Connection"],
    ["2", "connectorId", "100"],  
    ["2", "part_2", "bottomPanel_1"], 
    ["2", "transformation", nil]]

]
```

I need to group nested arrays by first element.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Give `a` your array, try this

```
a.group_by(&:first).values
 => [
  [["1", "className", "Connection"], 
  ["1", "connectorId", "100"], 
  ["1", "part_1", "side_1"], 
  ["1", "part_2", "bottomPanel_1"], 
  ["1", "transformation", nil]], 

  [["2", "className", "Connection"], 
  ["2", "connectorId", "100"], 
  ["2", "part_1", "side_1"], 
  ["2", "part_2", "bottomPanel_1"], 
  ["2", "transformation", nil]]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's `Enumerable` module has all kinds of goodies built into it, and [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) does very close to what you want.

```
arr.group_by { |x| x[0] } # Assuming your input array is called arr
```

This results in a dictionary where the keys are the groupings (i.e. the first elements of the inner arrays) and the values are the lists of elements in that group. That is,

```
{
  "1" => [
    ["1", "className", "Connection"],
    ["1", "connectorId", "100"],
    ["1", "part_1", "side_1"],
    ["1", "part_2", "bottomPanel_1"],
    ["1", "transformation", nil]
  ],
  "2" => [
    ["2", "className", "Connection"],
    ["2", "connectorId", "100"],
    ["2", "part_1", "side_1"],
    ["2", "part_2", "bottomPanel_1"],
    ["2", "transformation", nil]
  ]
}
```

If all you want are the groupings, not the keys, then we can just do

```
arr.group_by { |x| x[0] }.values
```

which gives you exactly the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are both correct, your end result still looks cumbersome to deal with. I would recommend taking this a step further so that the resulting object is easier to utilize

```
a =[
    ["1", "className", "Connection"], 
    ["2", "className", "Connection"], 
    ["1", "connectorId", "100"], 
    ["2", "connectorId", "100"], 
    ["1", "part_1", "side_1"], 
    ["2", "part_1", "side_1"], 
    ["1", "part_2", "bottomPanel_1"], 
    ["2", "part_2", "bottomPanel_1"], 
    ["1", "transformation", nil], 
    ["2", "transformation", nil]
   ]

# shift will mutate the inner Arrays 
# if this does not matter you can remove map(&:dup)

b = a.map(&:dup).group_by(&:shift).transform_values(&:to_h) 
#=> {"1"=>{
#       "className"=>"Connection", 
#       "connectorId"=>"100", 
#       "part_1"=>"side_1", 
#       "part_2"=>"bottomPanel_1", 
#       "transformation"=>nil}, 
#     "2"=>{
#       "className"=>"Connection", 
#       "connectorId"=>"100", 
#       "part_1"=>"side_1", 
#       "part_2"=>"bottomPanel_1", 
#       "transformation"=>nil}
#    }
```

Now the resulting `Object` is a `Hash` which will make accessing the data much easier. e.g. to access 1's connectorId

- Your Result: `b[0][1][2]` or `b.dig(0,1,2)`
- Hash Result: `b["1"]["connectorId"]`

Turning the results into a `Hash` will also allow for order independence in the event that the order of `a` is not as determinate as it is in the post.